# Error Loading another script in the JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

I am trying to create chart in my widget. I am using AM Charts for this purpose.
I am having a script file(.js) in which I am unable to load the AM Charts. The scripts are getting loaded but I am getting the error "AmCharts is not defined".

My Widget Code:

```
(function () {
    // Localize jQuery variable
    var jQuery;

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/


    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");

        if (script_tag.readyState) {
            script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                    scriptLoadHandler();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    }
    else {
        // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }



    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        main();
    }

    /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() {
        var LanguageVal = 1;
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var css_link = $("<link>", {
                rel: "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: "Content/css/DailyPrices.css"
            });
            css_link.appendTo('head');
            var css_link1 = $("<link>", {
                rel: "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                media:"all",
                href: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css"
            });
            css_link1.appendTo('head');

            var css_link2 = $("<script>", {
                type: "text/javascript",
                src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js",
            });
            css_link2.appendTo('head');

            var css_link3 = $("<script>", {
                type: "text/javascript",
                src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js",
            });
            css_link3.appendTo('head');
            var css_link4 = $("<script>", {
                type: "text/javascript",
                src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js",
            });
            css_link4.appendTo('head');
            var css_link5 = $("<script>", {
                type: "text/javascript",
                src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js",
            });
            css_link5.appendTo('head');

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:44360/api/TodayPrice/DailyPrice",
                data: { Language: LanguageVal },
                success: function (result) {
                    var list1 = result.data;
                    var list2 = result.HeaderLst;

                    var TodayDieselPrice = list1[0].TodayDieselPrice;
                    var TodayPetrolPrice = list1[0].TodayPetrolPrice;
                    var YesterdayDieselPrice = list1[0].YesterdayDieselPrice;
                    var YesterdayPetrolPrice = list1[0].YesterdayPetrolPrice;
                    var PetrolText = list1[0].PetrolText;
                    var DieselText = list1[0].DieselText;
                    var PetrolIconColor = list1[0].PetrolIconColor;
                    var DieselIconColor = list1[0].DieselIconColor;
                    var FirstHeader = list2[0].FirstHeader;
                    var SecondHeader = list2[0].SecondHeader;
                    var ThirdHeader = list2[0].ThirdHeader;
                    var FourthHeader = list2[0].FourthHeader;
                    var FifthHeader = list2[0].FifthHeader;
                    var LastHeader = list2[0].LastHeader;

                    $("#example-widget-container").append('<div class="WholeDiv row"><div class="col-md-12 firstrow"><div style="float:left;padding:8px">'+FirstHeader+'</div><div style="float:right"><img src="Content/images/Petrol-pump-icon.png"/></div></div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-12 secondrow"><div class="col-md-3">'+SecondHeader+'</div><div class="col-md-4">'+ThirdHeader+'</div><div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-3">'+FourthHeader+'</div></div><div class="col-md-12 thirdrow"><div class="col-md-3">'+PetrolText+'</div><div class="col-md-4">'+YesterdayPetrolPrice+'</div><div class="col-md-2"><div class="PIconColor"></div></div><div class="col-md-3">'+TodayPetrolPrice+'</div></div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-12 fourthrow"><div class="col-md-3">'+DieselText+'</div><div class="col-md-4">'+YesterdayDieselPrice+'</div><div class="col-md-2"><div class="DIconColor"></div></div><div class="col-md-3">'+TodayDieselPrice+'</div></div><div class="col-md-12 fifthrow"> <div  style="float:left"><a>'+FifthHeader+'</a></div> <div style="float:right" class="sponsorDiv"><div class="sponsorTextDiv">Powered By ICICI</div></div></div></div>');

                    $("#example-widget-container").append('<div id="chartdiv"></div>');

                    if (PetrolIconColor == "Red") {
                        $('.PIconColor').addClass('arrow-up');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.PIconColor').addClass('arrow-down');
                    }

                    if (DieselIconColor == "Red") {
                        $('.DIconColor').addClass('arrow-up');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.DIconColor').addClass('arrow-down');
                    }



                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(thrownError);
                }
            });

            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
                "type": "serial",
                "theme": "light",
                "marginRight": 70,
                "dataProvider": [{
                    "country": "USA",
                    "visits": 3025,
                    "color": "#FF0F00"
                }, {
                    "country": "China",
                    "visits": 1882,
                    "color": "#FF6600"
                }, {
                    "country": "Japan",
                    "visits": 1809,
                    "color": "#FF9E01"
                }, {
                    "country": "Germany",
                    "visits": 1322,
                    "color": "#FCD202"
                }, {
                    "country": "UK",
                    "visits": 1122,
                    "color": "#F8FF01"
                }, {
                    "country": "France",
                    "visits": 1114,
                    "color": "#B0DE09"
                }, {
                    "country": "India",
                    "visits": 984,
                    "color": "#04D215"
                }, {
                    "country": "Spain",
                    "visits": 711,
                    "color": "#0D8ECF"
                }, {
                    "country": "Netherlands",
                    "visits": 665,
                    "color": "#0D52D1"
                }, {
                    "country": "Russia",
                    "visits": 580,
                    "color": "#2A0CD0"
                }, {
                    "country": "South Korea",
                    "visits": 443,
                    "color": "#8A0CCF"
                }, {
                    "country": "Canada",
                    "visits": 441,
                    "color": "#CD0D74"
                }],
                "valueAxes": [{
                    "axisAlpha": 0,
                    "position": "left",
                    "title": "Visitors from country"
                }],
                "startDuration": 1,
                "graphs": [{
                    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
                    "fillColorsField": "color",
                    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
                    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                    "type": "column",
                    "valueField": "visits"
                }],
                "chartCursor": {
                    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                    "cursorAlpha": 0,
                    "zoomable": false
                },
                "categoryField": "country",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "gridPosition": "start",
                    "labelRotation": 45
                },
                "export": {
                    "enabled": true
                }

            });
        });
    }

})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately

HTML Code:

     <div id="example-widget-container"></div>
```

Comment: When it says AmCharts is not defined it means AmCharts  plugin is not loaded before running above script. or you have not imported it. can you share more detail when you are loading plugin and when above script. can  share console error if possible

Comment: If u look at the main function I have loaded the am charts plug in after jquery is loaded. In my page the scripts and stylesheets are getting loaded.The charts must be loaded on the page load itself.

Comment: In that case ajax calls works asynchronously so chances are there your  AmCharts  is running before AmCharts  plugin is loaded. just to confirm add timeout for your  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart function 
  like this setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

Comment: I think the problem is loading of the scripts of am charts. please tell me how to load am charts plugin before my script loads but it should be present in the same script file only

Answer (score 0):

Try following order atleast AmCharts issue seems to be resolved

```
function loadChart() {
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
                "type": "serial",
                "theme": "light",
                "marginRight": 70,
                "dataProvider": [{
                    "country": "USA",
                    "visits": 3025,
                    "color": "#FF0F00"
                }, {
                    "country": "China",
                    "visits": 1882,
                    "color": "#FF6600"
                }, {
                    "country": "Japan",
                    "visits": 1809,
                    "color": "#FF9E01"
                }, {
                    "country": "Germany",
                    "visits": 1322,
                    "color": "#FCD202"
                }, {
                    "country": "UK",
                    "visits": 1122,
                    "color": "#F8FF01"
                }, {
                    "country": "France",
                    "visits": 1114,
                    "color": "#B0DE09"
                }, {
                    "country": "India",
                    "visits": 984,
                    "color": "#04D215"
                }, {
                    "country": "Spain",
                    "visits": 711,
                    "color": "#0D8ECF"
                }, {
                    "country": "Netherlands",
                    "visits": 665,
                    "color": "#0D52D1"
                }, {
                    "country": "Russia",
                    "visits": 580,
                    "color": "#2A0CD0"
                }, {
                    "country": "South Korea",
                    "visits": 443,
                    "color": "#8A0CCF"
                }, {
                    "country": "Canada",
                    "visits": 441,
                    "color": "#CD0D74"
                }],
                "valueAxes": [{
                    "axisAlpha": 0,
                    "position": "left",
                    "title": "Visitors from country"
                }],
                "startDuration": 1,
                "graphs": [{
                    "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
                    "fillColorsField": "color",
                    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
                    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                    "type": "column",
                    "valueField": "visits"
                }],
                "chartCursor": {
                    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                    "cursorAlpha": 0,
                    "zoomable": false
                },
                "categoryField": "country",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "gridPosition": "start",
                    "labelRotation": 45
                },
                "export": {
                    "enabled": true
                }

            });
}


(function () {
    // Localize jQuery variable
    var jQuery;

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/


    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");



         var css_link = $("<link>", {
            rel: "stylesheet",
            type: "text/css",
            href: "Content/css/DailyPrices.css"
        });
        css_link.appendTo('head');
        var css_link1 = $("<link>", {
            rel: "stylesheet",
            type: "text/css",
            media:"all",
            href: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css"
        });
        css_link1.appendTo('head');

        var css_link2 = $("<script>", {
            type: "text/javascript",
            src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js",
        });
        css_link2.appendTo('head');

        var css_link3 = $("<script>", {
            type: "text/javascript",
            src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js",
        });
        css_link3.appendTo('head');



        if (script_tag.readyState) {
            script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                    scriptLoadHandler();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    }
    else {
        // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }



    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {


    setTimeout(function(){

        // wait for amchart to load 
         var css_link4 = $("<script>", {
            type: "text/javascript",
            src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js",
        });
        css_link4.appendTo('head');

        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
         var css_link5 = $("<script>", {
            type: "text/javascript",
            src: "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js",
        });
        css_link5.appendTo('head');

        main();


    }, 1000);

    }

    /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() {
        var LanguageVal = 1;
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:44360/api/TodayPrice/DailyPrice",
                data: { Language: LanguageVal },
                success: function (result) {
                    var list1 = result.data;
                    var list2 = result.HeaderLst;

                    var TodayDieselPrice = list1[0].TodayDieselPrice;
                    var TodayPetrolPrice = list1[0].TodayPetrolPrice;
                    var YesterdayDieselPrice = list1[0].YesterdayDieselPrice;
                    var YesterdayPetrolPrice = list1[0].YesterdayPetrolPrice;
                    var PetrolText = list1[0].PetrolText;
                    var DieselText = list1[0].DieselText;
                    var PetrolIconColor = list1[0].PetrolIconColor;
                    var DieselIconColor = list1[0].DieselIconColor;
                    var FirstHeader = list2[0].FirstHeader;
                    var SecondHeader = list2[0].SecondHeader;
                    var ThirdHeader = list2[0].ThirdHeader;
                    var FourthHeader = list2[0].FourthHeader;
                    var FifthHeader = list2[0].FifthHeader;
                    var LastHeader = list2[0].LastHeader;

                    $("#example-widget-container").append('<div class="WholeDiv row"><div class="col-md-12 firstrow"><div style="float:left;padding:8px">'+FirstHeader+'</div><div style="float:right"><img src="Content/images/Petrol-pump-icon.png"/></div></div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-12 secondrow"><div class="col-md-3">'+SecondHeader+'</div><div class="col-md-4">'+ThirdHeader+'</div><div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-3">'+FourthHeader+'</div></div><div class="col-md-12 thirdrow"><div class="col-md-3">'+PetrolText+'</div><div class="col-md-4">'+YesterdayPetrolPrice+'</div><div class="col-md-2"><div class="PIconColor"></div></div><div class="col-md-3">'+TodayPetrolPrice+'</div></div>'+
    '<div class="col-md-12 fourthrow"><div class="col-md-3">'+DieselText+'</div><div class="col-md-4">'+YesterdayDieselPrice+'</div><div class="col-md-2"><div class="DIconColor"></div></div><div class="col-md-3">'+TodayDieselPrice+'</div></div><div class="col-md-12 fifthrow"> <div  style="float:left"><a>'+FifthHeader+'</a></div> <div style="float:right" class="sponsorDiv"><div class="sponsorTextDiv">Powered By ICICI</div></div></div></div>');

                    $("#example-widget-container").append('<div id="chartdiv"></div>');

                    if (PetrolIconColor == "Red") {
                        $('.PIconColor').addClass('arrow-up');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.PIconColor').addClass('arrow-down');
                    }

                    if (DieselIconColor == "Red") {
                        $('.DIconColor').addClass('arrow-up');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.DIconColor').addClass('arrow-down');
                    }




                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(thrownError);
                }
            });

               loadChart();

        });
    }

})();
```